DataGrid Summaries at the last row
Currently I can achieve the summary at the bottom of screen like its always fixed, but what I want is that the summary of data at the last row. How can I achieve it using SFDataGrid.

As you can see on image its like stacked above the table itself but I want it at the last row where it gets visible when you reach the end
